# How to GET data from serverside (using mongoose) to clientside depending on the $stateparams in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose, mean-stack

So I have a list of users in my App which has a unique _id set automatically by mongoDB, what I wanted to do is to display the details of a specific user in a seperate page depending on its _id using $stateParams, for example if the url would be

```
http://localhost/project/users/576a5392357753bc22982cb9
```

and display the users detail with that `576a5392357753bc22982cb9` id in this specific page. But I am getting a 404 error. Please help I am still new to MEAN stack, if you need more of my codes I will provide it to help it solved the problem, and if there is more "specific and right way" to do it please tell me. thank you!

AngularJS Controller:

```
.controller("userDetailsCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams){

               $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/specificProfle', {
                      params: { id: $stateParams.id}
              })
               .then(function(success) {
                      $scope.datalist = success.data;
                      console.log($scope.datalist);
               })
               .catch(function(error) {
                      console.error(error);
               });
});
```

Routes:

```
.state('userDetails', {
        url: '/users/:id',
        templateUrl: 'scripts/components/user-details/userDetails.html',
        controller: "userDetailsCtrl"
    })
```

ExpressJS API:

```
router.get('/api/specificProfile', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
          Users.findOne({ _id : req.params._id}, function(err, user) {
                    res.send(user);
                    console.log(user);
          });
});
```

list of users HTML

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Users</h3>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat='user in datalist'>
                <td>
                    <a ui-sref="userDetails({id: user._id})" data-ng-hide="editMode">{{user.username}}</a>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-model="user.username" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{user.email}}</span>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-model="user.email" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{user.name}}</span>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-model="user.name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{user.phoneNumber}}</span>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-model="user.phoneNumber">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{user.role}}</span>
                    <select class="form-control" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-model="user.role">
                        <option>Administrator</option>
                        <option>Advertiser</option>
                        <option>Subscriber</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a a-href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = true"></a>
                    <a a-href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; update(user)"></a>
                    <a a-href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" ui-sref="user">Add New User</a>
</div>
```

where in the

```
ui-sref="userDetails({id: user._id})"
```

will handle the link going to userDetails page that will have a url/state whatever the _id of the user is in the users list page

**EDIT**

I found out that It's just a typo in the controller, it should be

```
http://localhost:3000/api/specificProfile
```

instead of

http://localhost:3000/api/specificProfle

mising "i" in the profile.

Now no more errors, but it throws as Null, maybe something wrong with my mongoose query?

Comment: 'But I am getting a 404 error'.. what error message are you getting?

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/api/specificProfle?id=576a5392357753bc22982cb9 404 (Not Found)

Comment: and in my $http request in the controller, in the .catch

Object {data: "<h1>Not Found</h1>↵<h2>404</h2>↵<pre>Error: Not Fo…\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:120:7)</pre>↵", status: 404, config: Object, statusText: "Not Found"}

Comment: does your router comply with this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/router#api

Comment: because it looks like your API is not working, and when it is trying to call it it cant find open link for that

Comment: I am just using the default way of routing things in ExpressJS, my other API is working well, just this one.

Comment: log the error in node and find out what it tells you

Comment: @charlietfl in my nodemon server.js cmd it also states 
GET /api/specificProfle?_id=576a5392357753bc22982cb9 404 14.894 ms - 2035

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few different way of how this can be done, here is how I would do this:

Express Router:

```
router.get('/api/:userId', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
      Users.findOne({ _id : req.params.userId}, function(err, user) {
                res.send(user);
                console.log(user);
      });
});
```

Another way is to use express middleware:

```
router.get('/api/:userId', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
      res.send(req.userProfile);
});
```

and middle-ware bindings

```
app.param('userId', users.userByID);


exports.userByID = function(req, res, next, id) {
    Users.findOne({ _id : req.params.userId}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!user) return next(new Error('Failed to load User ' + id));
      req.userProfile = user;
      next();
    });
};
```

Comment: I am getting this error after trying your first method

`{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: ':id',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined }`

Comment: can you console.log(req.params.userId) ?

Comment: you request format should be like this: GET localhost:3000/api/576a5392357753bc22982cb9

Comment: Yes what i did was to put /:id at the end of my $http request in the controller and also in the API. I also tried playing with /:_id etc with no luck.

Comment: can you console.log(req.params.userId) inside route.get ?